# Build Server Error

Tags: codenameone

I am having a problem building from the server. My project is an Android application using Netbeans IDE. When I run my application everything works fine, the the compiler reports no error at all. But when I send the server build Netbeans report a successful build but but when I login to the build server what i see there is a Build Fail with an error log.

The following is the error log I get from the build server:

```
Executing: /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/android create project --target android-14 --name MyApplication --path /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication --activity MyApplicationStub --package com.mycompany.myapp Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/src/com/mycompany/myapp
Added file /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/src/com/mycompany/myapp/MyApplicationStub.java
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/bin
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/libs
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res/values
Added file /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res/values/strings.xml
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res/layout
Added file /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res/layout/main.xml
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res/drawable-hdpi
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res/drawable-mdpi
Created directory /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/res/drawable-ldpi
Added file /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/AndroidManifest.xml
Added file /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/build.xml
Added file /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/proguard-project.txt
Executing: /home/ec2-user/android/ant/bin/ant release Buildfile: /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is proguard.cfg
     [echo] Proguard.config is enabled

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.2.1
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/ec2-user/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MyApplication
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 18.1.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyApplication...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.0
[gettarget] API level:        14
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyApplication...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'release'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 405 source files to /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/bin/classes
    [javac] /tmp/build4676848571336833460xxx/MyApplication/src/com/mycompany/myapp/MyApplicationStub.java:119: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac] i.start();
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error
```

BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 26 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add exception `throws` statements to the `start()` callback.

Comment: Thank you Mr Shai Almog, My App just got built its working fine